# Allow consecutive subscript

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

Apparently, LaTeX does not like `x_a_b`. This is an issue when I want to type `\game{1}_Z` as depending on the way `\game` is defined, it may finish with a subscript like `Game_1`. I tried to define `\game` using braces like `{Game_1}`, but then superscript displays poorly:

[image]

I could of course define `\game` to take additional parameters for the subscript/superscript, but it would not only complicate a bit the syntax, but also complicates it's usage: indeed, I designed a function `\refGame` that prints the title of a game that may contain internally `\game` (but it is not mandatory), and I still want to be able to do `\refGame{label}_Z` if `\refGame{label}` expands to `\game{1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\game}[1]{{\texttt{Game}_{#1}}}


\begin{document}

What I get: $\game{1}^A$, $\game{2}_Z$ and $\game{3}^A_Z$

What I want: $\texttt{Game}_1^A$, $\texttt{Game}_{2Z}$ and $\texttt{Game}_{3,Z}^A$

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to ask to LaTeX to understand `x_a_b` as `x_{ab}`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the comma is not mandatory. If you know how to add a comma when we put two consecutive subscripts it's great, otherwise no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\game{me{_^}}
 {%
   \texttt{Game}%
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {_{#1}}
    {_{#1,#2}}%
  \IfNoValueF{#3}{^#3}%  
 }

\begin{document}

What I get: $\game{1}$, $\game{1}^A$, $\game{2}_Z$ and $\game{3}^A_Z$ $\game{3}_Z^A$

\end{document}
```

will give

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's clever... (+1, I'll accept if my comment can't be addressed) By any chance do you also have a way to make it pass through `hyperlink`? The reason is that `\refGame` wraps this `\game` into a hyperref, like `\refGame{blabla}^A` expands into `\hyperlink{blabla}{\game{1}}^A`, and when I try your code with this the alignment is bad.

Comment: no sorry I will not change my answer. I really hate it when people expand the question after an answer has been given and make the answer more or less invalid. That is a misuse of my time. Ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Fair enough. And sorry for asking related questions, I just wanted to avoid spamming with many related questions, it was not meant to upset you in any way. Also, sometimes it's hard to pin-point directly what is exactly needed. Often one solution shows new issues appearing...